# Express $T$, $N$ and $B$ unitary vectors in terms of $\sigma$ (not necessary an arc length parametrization).

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $\sigma:[a, b] \to C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a parametrization of a curve $C$.

I want to express $T$, $N$ and $B$ unitary vectors in terms of $\sigma$. The main problem is that I cannot find a short way to express these unitary vectors.

For example:

$$T' = \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big) \sigma''- \Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big) \sigma' = \Bigg(\Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)x''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)x', \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)y''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)y', \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)z''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)z' \Bigg)$$
and
$$|| T' || = \sqrt{\Bigg(\Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)x''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)x'\Bigg)^2+\Bigg( \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)y''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)y'\Bigg)^2+\Bigg( \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)z''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)z' \Bigg)^2}$$
Then
$$N = \frac{\Bigg(\Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)x''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)x', \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)y''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)y', \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)z''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)z' \Bigg)}{\sqrt{\Bigg(\Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)x''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)x'\Bigg)^2+\Bigg( \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)y''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)y'\Bigg)^2+\Bigg( \Big(\frac{1}{|| \sigma' ||}\Big)z''-\Big(\frac{\sigma'' \cdot \sigma'}{|| \sigma' ||^3}\Big)z' \Bigg)^2}}$$

Is it a short way to write $N$ and $B$ in terms of $\sigma$?

Comment: You don't have to write $T'$ again with its components.

Comment: Thats the most we can reduce these vectors. They are not as simple as $\kappa$ and $\tau$ in terms of $\sigma$. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use just vector expressions (no components)? Especially since your wrote at the beginning that $\sigma$ maps to $\Bbb R^n$. The expanded form is not helpful in the least.

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe it was the answer I was waiting for. Thanks!